# Moving an element along a curved path as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll

I'm trying to make a page where a rocket follows a predetermined path which snakes up the page (the page will load at the bottom) as the user scrolls.

I can animate an element along a path using something like [jQuery.path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) and using SVG's animateMotion but I can't quite figure out a solution where the element would move along that path as the user scrolls.

jQuery Scroll Path isn't quite what I'm looking for as it moves the elements into the center of the page.

I've seen on the [TEDxGUC](http://www.tedxguc.com/) website, they move the apple along a curved path as you scroll down. I can see they're using Raphael.js and an 'animation along a path' extension but I still can't get my head around how they've actually achieved it – I'm not quite a JS ninja just yet.

Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated!

**EDIT**

For anyone still interested in this kind of thing, I stumbled across [Skrollr Path](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-path), which pretty much does exactly what I was looking for: [example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-path/)

Comment: Any word on the Skrollr Path plugin? There is absolutely no documentation or any information of any kind other than the actual plugin and the demo page provided. Just wondering if you have any more information about it you could share. Thanks

Comment: I would love to see any code you may have working with using Skrollr Path. It is exactly what I need, but I am having a really hard time working with this plugin.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't had the opportunity to play around with it yet. Have you checked out the main [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) library? If you read the documentation for that and then check out the source for the [Skrollr Path example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-path/), you might be able to work out the basics. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: I have not had too much time to check it out, I'll check into the main Skrollr library. Thanks. For whatever reason, I can't get anything to properly render with the Skrollr path plugin even when I copy the demo source exactly. I can't figure out what is going wrong. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the developer of the www.tedxguc.com website.

I think you're already on the right path (pun intended) with regards to how I got the animation to work with the scrolling. I simply conceptualized the animation as if the scroll bar is a seek bar in a video player.

So I set the height of the page to the length of my animation, such that every  1 pixel my element moves correspond to 1 ms in the animation, as if I was moving in a timeline.

You'll notice the animation set up code at the end of the [homepage.js](http://www.tedxguc.com/js/homepage.js) file.

In makeAnim() you'll find a lot of code that looks like this

```
setAnim(obj.apple,{0:{along:0}, 1000:{along:1}}, start+3200, 1000);
```

What this basically does is: set up the apple such that it will move from it's 0 (start of the path) to 1 (end of path) and it will do so within 1000px of scrolling
starting form the "start" of animation + an offset of 3200 pixels.

I kind of cheated and fixed the code a bit to make it simpler to understand.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Draz/R8Mxq/8/) of the earlier concept in development and I hope my comment helped.

Comment: Thanks – this is really useful. I still haven't had a chance to dig into your fiddle but I'll report back when I do!

Comment: The scope of the project I was working on changed slightly and I ended up using CSS Animations to replicate the rockets movement (you can see [here](http://www.cnduk.org/scraptrident/)). However, you did answer my original question so I've marked it as correct – thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your formula that takes y value and computes x but here's what I came up with...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zCuEb

HTML

```
<div id="oh" style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:100px;position:fixed"></div>
<div style="height:25000px;width:20px;background-color:#000033">&nbsp;</div>
```

JS

```
var $w = $(window);
var $d = $('#oh');
$w.scroll(function(){
  $d.css('left',formula400())
});
function formula400(){
  return Math.sin($w.scrollTop()/100)*100
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really cool! If I can work out the right formula I need, this might be a workable solution.

Comment: I realised in my original plans, the rocket actually travels horizontally at times, as it's almost a square snaking path. I don't think this is possible with your method as the vertical scroll would essentially have to stop. I've put together a solution that would use fixed positioning for the rocket and just move it left and right at certain points but this isn't perfect. I just thought of a way I might be able to do it using Skrollr.js – I'll report back!